# How uninstall apache server from cpanel?

Tags: apache, tomcat, uninstallation, cpanel, vps

I would like to know how can I completely uninstall the apache server from my vps which is configured with cpanel. Are there there any other dependencies to apache server on a regular cpanel installation?

PS. I am using on my vps server this particular services: tomcat, bind and courier mail server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from whm. Login to http://yoururl/whm, there you will have options for each package(control panel).

Answer (score 4):

If you are running the latest Apache, use this:

```
yum remove ea-apache24
```